# Classification of complex irreducible representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Is there a classification of complex irreducible representations of the group $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field with $q$ elements?

Comment: Did you even make an attempt to e.g. google this?  It's a well-documented subject.  The character table was found by Green (see https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-080-02/S0002-9947-1955-0072878-2/S0002-9947-1955-0072878-2.pdf; if I recall correctly, this is also discussed in Fulton-Harris), and the literature after that is vast.

Comment: If you are a beginner, the n=2 case is a good place to start.  The book "Complex Representations of GL(2, K) for Finite Fields K" (Contemporary Mathematics volume 16) by Ilya Piatetski-Shapiro is excellent.

Comment: As to $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb q)$, the beautiful book *Representations and Characters of Groups* by James and Liebeck has a chapter devoted to that.

Comment: The trouble with answering this question is that, on the one hand, there is a ton of literature, but on the other hand it is (or is for me) very hard to point to a place which has it all. This highly rated question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203602/learning-deligne-lusztig-theory has an overview, but it may be quite overwhelming for a newcomer.

Comment: Here is what I understand: For any positive integer $k$, let $T(q^k)$ be the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$. Let $T(q^{\infty})$ be $\bigcup T(q^k)$; there is a natural Frobenius action on $T(q^{\infty})$ by $\theta \mapsto \theta^q$. Conjugacy classes of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ are indexed by functions $\lambda$ from $T(q^{\infty})$ to the set of partition which are Frob-invariant, such that $\sum_{\theta} |\lambda(\theta)|=n$. (This is rational normal form.) So these are the rows of a the character table  (continued)

Comment: Let $X(q^k) = \text{Hom}(T(q^k), \mathbb{C}^{\ast})$. For $a|b$, we have a surjection (the norm map) $T(q^b) \to T(q^a)$ and thus a dual injection $X(q^a) \to X(q^b)$; let $X(q^{\infty})$ be the direct limit of all these injections. Then representations of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ are indexed by functions $\chi$ from $X(q^{\infty})$ to partitions which are Frob invariant, such that $\sum |\chi(\theta)| = n$. So these are the columns of the character table.

Comment: I'm going to stop. I learned more than this, but I didn't learn it well, and I'm worried about making errors. But I do think that this is an area that is hard to learn from googling. I think it would be worthwhile for someone to either write or link to a reference that tells the whole story, going through parabolic induction, Hecke algebras, Deligne-Lusztig induction, etc ...

Comment: Someone must have taught a good graduate course that has all this!

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, I think your comments are great, and would love to see them converted to an answer.

Comment: @LSpice I'm hoping someone who knows this better will do the job! Otherwise, I need to figure out which notes I was reading two years ago ...

Comment: Even though this question is closed, I too would love to see a reference to a graduate course going over all this.